# Can you suspend a dust collector motor from the ceiling with chains?

Tags: dust-collection

To be clear, I'm not talking about an air filtration unit, which is often suspended from the ceiling using chains...I'm talking about a fan used in one and two stage dust collection systems.  Mine happens to be the small, cheap Wen that's notoriously loud.

In an effort to reduce noise, would it be possible to suspend the dust collector from the ceiling using chains or would there be too much momentum/movement?  My system's duct work will run along the ceiling and drop down to various tools and stations, so the floor isn't an option.  But to minimize noise traveling through the walls, I had the idea to hang it from the ceiling using four chains.  Just wanted to know if the reason I can't find any info on this is because it's a big fat *no*.

Thanks!

Comment: I think if this is good idea someone else will have done it and you would find info so maybe you have answered question already :)

Comment: Turn it on and pick it up? See how it feels and if a chain can take it. If there is just a little lateral movement, try fixating with some ropes on opposite walls.

Comment: Although you might get some good input on this here from people who have assembled dust-collection setups I suspect you have answered your own query by not being able to find anything on doing this. Given the Wen is notoriously loud, I presume there must be existing strategies to deal with this like boxing the unit in, using vibration-absorbing packing between the unit and the floor or wall?

Comment: Why is the floor not an option? The tools at the other ends of the ducts are on the floor, aren't they?

Comment: For a reason _why_ it probably isn't done, I can only imagine the torque from the motor would only make the housing want to twist in equal and an opposite direction that the fan is supposed to spin. Hanging from chains, there's nothing much to resist this twist, so the whole thing ends up dancing all around the ceiling, whipping chains and flexible ducting around, and breaking or breaking itself loose from rigid ducting. If you've got some chain sturdy enough to support it, though, there's nothing wrong with giving it a try... (con't)

Comment: I'd want each of 4 chains to be able to support the full weight of the motor plus some extra. That way, you've got at least 4 times the breaking strength, just in case one gives way, there are still 3. Do be prepared to turn it off quickly!

Comment: To add to @FreeMan comment, once you hang it and figure out if it wants to shimmy/twist, you could add additional bungy cords at angles that oppose the twist.

Comment: Welcome to WSE. This is not really a woodworking question and as you can see it is not generating any definitive answers. IMO suspending the unit can only reduce any direct contact vibration at the units contact points.  The bulk of the noise is coming from the operation of the motor and air movement which will still be present.  The only way I know of to reduce the noise appreciably is to move it to a solid enclosure away from the work area.  I am closing this question as off topic.  Please take the [tour](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/)  to learn more about this site.

Comment: I voted to reopen because this is a directly parallel to numerous queries that we have dealt with in the past. Just because it hasn't yet attracted a good Answer (or any Answer for that matter LOL) doesn't inherently make it a bad Question.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable fit to me.

Comment: Even if you could, I don't see how it would reduce noise to be honest because the chains are non-elastic and under tension which would transmit all the vibration to the ceiling anyways. It doesn't seem that different to me from just bolting it the ceiling other than some lateral motion might not reach the ceiling.